# Is there a way to specify Maven profile alias or multiple profile ids not using -D?

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I want to use the same Maven profile using different profile ids (aliases) like in the following:

> mvn validate -Pintegration-test-A

and also:

> mvn validate -PitA

I tried:

```
<profile>
    <id>integration-test-A,itA</id>
    ...
</profile>
```

of course, it's treated as a single long profile name *integration-test-A,itA*

then also did:

```
<profile>
    <id>integration-test-A</id>
    <id>itA</id>
    ...
</profile>
```

and this can't pass XSD validation

I know that there's no way to chain Maven profiles (could be a workaround).
I can go:

```
<profile>
    <id>integration-test-A</id>
    <activation>
        <property><name>itA</name></property>
    </activation>
    ...
</profile>
```

but that would imply

> mvn validate -DitA

instead of *-PitA* and support-wise I would prefer not to confuse -D and -P things in our different use-cases just to make it easier for other teammates to understand it's still a profile but enabled with its short name.

Of course, copying profile snippets but with different ids is not an option.

I can see nothing helpful to me in the official doc http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.
Looking for an analog of long+short options usual CLI feature for Maven profiles configured in POM files only.
Any ideas?
Or is it true there's no such a possibility right now when using Maven?

EDIT:

Long and short names of example profile are arbitrary.

Preference for -P over -D is because we use a lot -D arguments and it would be just easier to find profiles directly seeing -P among in a lot of -Ds in the commands representing our use cases.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a maven wrapper shell script which sets the correct profile rather than introducing aliases? I assume the goal is to save typing. Not having to type stuff at all wins every time in my book.

Comment: Actually, having profiles for different test stages is usually not the best solution. Generally, one should avoid to have more than (say) five different profiles in total.

Comment: Apart from what JF Meier said. Why not simply using `-PitA`? why do you need an alias? What's the advantage? I don't understand the mentioning of `-D` and `-P` cause only `-P` is for activting/deactivating profiles?

Comment: @JFMeier, the names (ids) are arbitrary. I just wanted to explain the difference between long and short names. So they may look against best practices.
But I can't say I can agree on the general rule you stated about having not more than (say) five profiles in total. It's hard to imagine it applied to a multi module project.

Comment: @khmarbaise, imagine we have something like:
`mvn install -Dprop1 -Dprop2 -Dprop3 -Dprof1 -Dprop4`
I would prefer to use shorter names sometimes (e.g. when typing manually).
So `mvn install -Dprop1 -Dprop2 -Dprop3 -Pprof1 -Dprop4` is easier to read and comprehend in my opinion.

Comment: But where do all these properties come from? When I build locally, I usually just run `mvn clean install` (also for multi-module projects), without putting properties on the command ilne.

Comment: All builds I do are just `mvn clean verify` locally on CI we one profile for JaCoCo ..that's it...no other profile or properties needed. And I always tell if you need to have those profiles/properties reconsider the need of them..it shows usually design/technical flaws etc. I had a compony which had 52 profiles and of course no one knew what they are for ..so after cleaning we have left with a single profile ...which was only needed on CI ...

Comment: But you basically reject the very idea of Maven profiles.
I suggest to leave out the discussion about necessity of profiles. I just use this feature of Maven and want to know if it's possible to use multiple profile IDs or aliases.

Comment: I am not against using profiles, they are an invaluable tool to work around the fact that builds can happen in different environments and need some environment-specific tailoring. But that is usually something set in stone; the OS (Windows, Linux, Mac), local development or doing a production build (often managed through a build server pipeline).  In this case you seem to have to specify a profile and build properties even when doing local builds... that is very unusual. Explaining how the project is setup might help to guide people beyond the "wut, why are you using profiles like this?" phase